# trying to create a simple standalone executable [Cython] issues

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, cython, executable

I am trying to create a simple standalone executable without needing for python to be installed on their system.

```
hello.py --embed
```

Creates a C file.

The following below:

```
   gcc hello.c -IC:\Users\Bain3\1\ -LC:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\python3.dll -lC:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\ -o hello1.py
```

Just gives me:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working.  I've tried everything from reinstalling to changing directories.

I have also tried:

```
cython --embed -o helloworld.c helloworld.py

gcc -c  helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe -I/Python34/include
```

This does create an executable but gives me the message below...
[image]

Comment: Works for me in linux

Comment: @JohnsonCave I restarted pc and got: hello1.py
hello.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.  As far as I can tell the directory is correct.

Comment: Your gcc command line isn't correct. A way to know the right flags/paths on your system would be to build a normal cython extension via setup-file and look at the resulting command line.

Comment: @ead I have tried:     cython --embed -o helloworld.c helloworld.py

    gcc -c  helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe -I/Python34/include.  Which does allow me to create an exe but it does allow me to run

Comment: You cannot rely on Cython to produce a standalone executable. The executable is also dependent on a python environment.

Comment: @oz1 I see.  So you'd need py2exe.  I'm not sure how you'd integrate that with Cython though... HMM

Comment: @oz1 That's not correct at all, Cython is known to create standalone executables